# Estimating termination of trajectory of a non-stationary random variable

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Imagine we have a random variable that is normally distributed and observed over time. The $\mu$ parameter of the normal distribution is 0 to begin with and $\sigma$ is fixed. Over time, $\mu$ shifts from 0 to 10 and then remains fixed.

How do we detect when $\mu$ has stopped moving (within some tolerance e.g. +/- 0.5 of the termination value) based on observations of the random variable when its initial and termination values (0 and 10 in the example) as well as its trajectory are unknown however $\mu$ is nondecreasing (the trajectory is always in one direction)?

I am looking for direction towards general solutions to this sort of problem (not to my particular example). If there is no general solution, then solutions to particular instantiations of this sort of problem given different assumptions.

Comment: That said, before doing any of that... I suggest that you'll probably need to edit the question to provide more details before we can answer the question. What approaches have you considered, and why did you reject them?  What research have you done?  How do you plan to evaluate possible answers?  Strictly speaking the question as you have stated it is not solvable: it's not possible to distinguish between a case where the r.v. has $\mu=10-\varepsilon$ (say, $\mu=9.9999$) and is moving slowly towards 10, vs where the r.v. has $\mu=10$ and has stopped moving.  What do you want to do about that?

Comment: Once more. How many samples we are talking about? "shifts from 0 to 10 and then remains fixed." this is nondecreasing? Why this is CS? There is statistics course during CS studies but Physical Education also - but we are not going to discuss how to do push ups here...

Comment: I've tried to clarify the sort of answer that I want in the question. I am not a statistician and want to understand what algorithms are considered as a solution to this problem rather than a particular solution. I don't know where to start. (I've flagged this to move it to stats.se)

Comment: What sort of values for $n$ and $\sigma$ might you have?

Comment: EvilJS asked above, but: do you know that $\mu(t)$ is nondecreasing, or could it be anything?

Comment: I'll update the question again. I know that it is non-decreasing.